# Eager loading with limit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How do I add a `limit` to this scope?

```
scope :with_comments, include: {comments: :user}
```

I'm using it like this:

```
Event.with_comments.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: check this question you will get your answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808674/rails-eager-load-and-limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scope :with_comments, include(comments: :user).limit(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
default_scope includes(:comments :user).limit(5)
```

Add it to default scope

```
Event.find(params[:id])
```