# How to filter associated records from controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I have two models, `Article` and `Comment` with a one-to-many relation.

My view looks like this:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <% article.comments.each do |comment| %>
    some content
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It's easy to filter the `@articles` from the controller, e.g:

```
@articles = Article.order('created_at asc').last(4)
```

And I could easily filter the comments in my view:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <% article.comments.order('created_at asc').last(4).each do |comment| %>
    some content
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But I don't want to put the `order('created_at asc').last(4)` logic in my view. How can I filter the article's comments from within the controller?

Comment: I've edited your question according to your comments. Feel free to change it if something is wrong, missing or unclear.

Comment: You edited it perfectly my friend!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this in the model

```
Class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, -> { order 'created_at' } do
    def recent
      limit(4)
    end
  end
end
```

and then use it as follows in the view

```
@articles.each do |article| 
    article.comments.recent.each do |comment|
        stuff
    end
end
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15284499/2511498, props to Shane

Comment: I like the logic a lot. However, I get `Unknown key: :order`

Comment: Edited. Looks like the answer I took for reference was a bit outdated. Also you don't need to specify 'ASC' in order as it is the default option.